# If $\frac{\sin x}{\sin y}= {3}$ and $\frac{\cos x}{\cos y}= \frac{1}{2}$, then find $\frac{\sin2x}{\sin2y}+\frac{\cos2x}{\cos2y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, fractions

> Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers such that $\dfrac{\sin x}{\sin y}= {3}$ and  $\dfrac{\cos x}{\cos y}= \dfrac{1}{2}$. Find a value of $$\dfrac{\sin2x}{\sin2y}+\dfrac{\cos2x}{\cos2y}.$$

My attempts:

Using the given condition and double angle formula, 
$\dfrac{\sin2x}{\sin2y} = \dfrac{3}{2}$

Now I am struggling to find the value of $\dfrac{\cos2x}{\cos2y}$

The simplest form I could reach was: 
$\dfrac{2\cos^2x-1}{8\cos^2x-1}$

How do I continue from here? Simpler methods to solve the problem are welcome.

PS: The answer is $\dfrac{49}{58}$

Comment: How did you get $\frac{3}{2}$? Shouldn't it be $\frac{\sin 2x}{\sin 2y} = \frac{1}{6}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sin{y}=3\sin{x}$ and $\cos{y}=2\cos{x}$.

Thus,
$$1=\sin^2y+\cos^2y=9\sin^2x+4\cos^2x=4+5\sin^2x,$$
which is impossible.

If $\sin{y}=\frac{1}{3}\sin{x}$ we obtain:
$$1=\sin^2y+\cos^2y=\frac{1}{9}\sin^2x+4\cos^2x=\frac{1}{9}+\frac{35}{9}\sin^2x.$$
Now, you can get $\sin^2x$, $\sin^2y$ and the rest for you.

Comment: @Abcd We have no  contradictions in math! I think there is a mistake in the given.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$\sin (y)=\frac {1}{3}\sin(x) $$
$$\cos (y )=2\cos (x) $$

$$\implies \sin^2(x )+36\cos^2 (x)=9$$
$$\implies  35\cos^2 (x)=8$$
$$\implies \cos^2 (x)=\frac {8}{35} $$

the second expression is
$$\frac {16-35}{64-35}=-19/29$$
the final result is
$$3/2-19/29=49/58$$